# I want to backup my database to a location where i want using a c# windows form application

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to backup my Oracle database named "XE" with all tables to a ".bak" file on a location where i want. I'm using OracleClient library

Specific classes i used for connection:
OracleConnection
OracleCommand

But i keep getting this:

System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
'

Don't know where i'm wrong :'(

Have tried using OleDBConnection & OleDBCommand too but got the same error :'(

```
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

 OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=XE;User ID=system;password=123;Unicode=true");
 cmd.Connection = con;

        string databaseName = null;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from global_name";

        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
            databaseName = Convert.ToString(row[0]);
            MessageBox.Show("" + databaseName);
        }
        con.Close();

        cmd.CommandText = "backup DATABASE " + databaseName + " TO DISK = '" + back_path.Text + "\\" + back_file_name.Text + ".bak'";
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Exception i got: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
'

Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException' in System.Data.OracleClient.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled exceptionNekron.exeSystem.Data.OracleClient.OracleException, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)

Comment: 1) Debug app 2) Grab generated query 3) Run in Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: how do i grab the generated query? in visual studio?

Comment: Debug mode or simply print: `cmd.CommandText`;

Comment: It has generated this: CommandText "BACKUP DATABASE XE TO DISK = 'C:\\Users\\UnKnown\\Desktop\\lul.bak'" string

Comment: What command were you aiming for? `BACKUP DATABASE` isn't an SQL command in Oracle, hence the ORA-0900.